# Angular: How to change value of formgroup when formgroup has changed value?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular-reactive-forms, formgroups

I'm a sieucapvipropeople.

I want to set value for a formControl in a formGroup when another formControl in this fromGroup has changed value

I try this but catch error: `maximum call stack size exceeded angular`:

```html
this.formGroup.get('DepreciationConfigInfo')
      ?.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((depreciationConfigInfo) => {
          this.formGroup.get('DepreciationConfigInfo')
          ?.get('DepreciationEnd')?.setValue(5)
        })
```

This is the FormGroup, I try to catch the event DepreciationPeriod or DepreciationStart change value:

```html
DepreciationConfigInfo: new UntypedFormGroup({
  DepreciationPeriod: new UntypedFormControl(),
  DepreciationStart: new UntypedFormControl(),
  DepreciationEnd: new UntypedFormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
 
}),
```

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.formGroup.get('DepreciationConfigInfo')
      ?.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
        .subscribe((depreciationConfigInfo) => {
          this.formGroup.get('DepreciationConfigInfo')
          ?.get('DepreciationEnd')?.setValue(5, { emitEvent: false })
        })
```

Do not trigger an event, this way the form control doesn't react to the change.

Comment: you can use "dot notation" in "get" `this.formGroup.get('DepreciationConfigInfo.DepreciationEnd')?.setValue(..)`

Comment: Not the point but cool to know.